# How can I block all internet access on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, internet

I want to stop being able to access the internet during my working day. Is there any tool that I can use to disable internet connectivity for a specified period of time? I'm using Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 3):

You can disable your network interfaces

typing "ifconfig" at the command line will print all of your network interfaces.

you can bring down an interface like this

> sudo ifconfig eth0 down

where eth0 is the network interface you are disconnecting, such as your wireless or wired Ethernet.

when you are ready to use it again just bring it back up.

> sudo ifconfig eth0 up

Comment: Thanks Chandler - what I am trying to do is prevent myself from surfing the web, is there a way to set a time parameter when I do this?

Comment: You could put those two commands in roots crontab at specific times.  So lines like 
"0 8 * * * ifconfig eth0 down"
"0 17 * * * ifconfig eth0 up"
will turn off the interface at 8am and turn it on at 5pm.  You can also specify certain days of the week.  See `man -s 5 crontab`

Comment: A small note: to get the list of network interfaces, `ifconfig | grep -P '^\S+'` (or `nmcli d`, if available) can be used instead of plain `ifconfig`, which dumps the full configuration data.

Answer (score 1):

I use [LeechBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4476/) for Firefox at work. Block your biggest time wasters and you'll soon get back to work.

You can still access the rest of the web to do work-related searches (say), so you don't look like a complete nutter to your colleagues if they are at your screen.

Answer (score 0):

**[Self Control](http://svn.jklmnop.net/projects/SelfControl.html)**  ([Download Link](http://svn.jklmnop.net/projects/SelfControl/selfcontrol_0.9-1_all.deb))

From [OMG!Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/self-control-ubuntu/)

> Self Control allows you to ‘block access to incoming and/or outgoing mail servers and websites’ for a specified amount of time.

[image: Self Control Screenshot]

Comment: This software is now [abandoned, and the authors discourage its use](https://github.com/zengargoyle/SelfControl).

Answer (score -1):

I just unplug the network cable when i'm not using the internet. This won't work for wireless connections, but i would reccommend using it if you have a wired connection (probably in addition to software disable).